# Controlling where Pulumi creates k8s namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

I need to write a new Pulumi program to do some k8s stuff. One task is creating new namespaces in different clusters.

What I *want* to do should look like this:

```js
    const ns1 = new k8s.core.v1.Namespace("foo-ns", {cluster: "foo_cluster"});
    const ns2 = new k8s.core.v1.Namespace("bar-ns", {cluster: "bar_cluster"});
```

I've looked at the docs for Namespaces (https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/kubernetes/api-docs/core/v1/namespace/) and I'm not really sure how I can control where the namespaces will get created. I see that there is an option to pass in a cluster name (https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/kubernetes/api-docs/core/v1/namespace/#clustername_nodejs) but the documents says

> The name of the cluster which the object belongs to. This is used to distinguish resources with same name and namespace in different clusters. **This field is not set anywhere right now and apiserver is going to ignore it** if set in create or update request.

(emphasis is mine)

So now I wonder: if I tell Pulumi to create a new namespace, in which cluster will the namespace be created?

(I was going to also ask about creating namespaces in similarly-named clusters in different GKE environments in different GCP projects - as that might be the next phase of this code, but I don't see a point if I can't specify different clusters in the same project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a resource provider, concretely, an explicit [resource provider](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/resources/providers/#explicit-provider-configuration)

The [Kubernetes resource provider](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/kubernetes/api-docs/provider/) supports a variety of ways to configure access to clusters, such as passing a `kubeconfig` or Kubernetes context:

```js
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";

const cluster1 = new k8s.Provider("cluster1", {
  cluster: "cluster1" // use the cluster with name "cluster1" in your default kubeconfig
});

const cluster2 = new k8s.Provider("cluster2", {
  kubeconfig: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./kubeconfig.yaml") // use a different kubeconfig entirely
});

 const ns1 = new k8s.core.v1.Namespace("foo-ns", {}, {provider: cluster1});
 const ns2 = new k8s.core.v1.Namespace("bar-ns", {}, {provider: cluster2});
```